# redux-saga: How to ignore one error and get other responses in parallel tasks?

Tags: javascript, generator, redux-saga

Here is my code, fetch several reports in parallel :

```
function fetchSingleReportRequest(reportId) {
   return axios.get(`/api/${reportId}`)
}

function* fetchReportsInfo({payload: {data: reportIds}}) {
   try {
     const responses = yield all(reportIds.map(reportId => 
      call(fetchSingleReportRequest, reportId)))
   } catch (e) {

   }
}
```

However, one or more report may doesn't exist, but it doesn't effect the result, the error could be ignored.

But when a 404 fetch happened, it enter the catch block, how can I get the other successsful responses ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Descend your try-catch logic down into the anonymous function. That way you can define what to do each time a call fails. Here for example, I just return `null` on a fail here.

```
function fetchSingleReportRequest(reportId) {
   return axios.get(`/api/${reportId}`)
}

function* fetchReportsInfo({payload: {data: reportIds}}) {
  const responses = yield all(reportIds.map(reportId => {
    try {
      return call(fetchSingleReportRequest, reportId)
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This happens because you are not handling the error in the Promise itself.

You just need to add a `catch` block to the `axios` request inside `fetchSingleReportRequest`.

For example, you can write something like:

```
function fetchSingleReportRequest(reportId) {
   return axios.get(`/api/${reportId}`)
     .catch(() => {
       return null
     })
}

function* fetchReportsInfo({payload: {data: reportIds}}) {
   try {
     let responses = yield all(reportIds.map(reportId => 
      call(fetchSingleReportRequest, reportId)))
     responses = responses.filter((res) => res !== null)
   } catch (e) {

   }
}
```